# Is my laptop improvable (and does it worth it)?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I'm studying graphic design and as soon as i've installed and used illustrator freezing problems started (with complex illustrations). Than i've realized that my laptop isn't qualified enough. I was wondering if i can change my laptop's motherboard / processor / graphics card with a better one. My laptop is 6 years old so i don't know even if it worths the change. Here are the [mother board and processor info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spKa7.jpg) and [graphics card info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F49hb.jpg) 
If it worths the change, i hope you can make suggestions too, thank you.

Comment: `Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Honestly it's not worth it maybe it's possible to upgrade it but it will cost you as much as getting a fair new laptop instead my advice is try to sell your old laptop for as much as you can get and get a new one no need to buy some super new tech like a core i5 5th or 6th generation with 8gb of ddr3 ram and a nvidia graphic card with 2gb up to 4gb is sufficient to get your work to be done .

Answer (score -1):

Laptops do not have standard hardware like custom PC's do, therefore it's not generally possible to do what you're asking. Your best bet is to purchase a new laptop that is within the requirements of the software you're running.